# Erro de DLL:api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll ao executar o Python

Tags: python-3.x

Após eu terminar a instalação do Python no meu computador, ao executar o Python em meu CMD apareceu a seguinte mensagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei reinstalar o Python mais de 3 vezes não funcionou, também tentei baixar a atualização *update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows* mas não funcionou, ao abrir o executável da atualização fiquei meia hora esperando e nada aconteceu.
 Depois disso baixei a dll separadamente e inseri no computar mas mesmo assim o problema persistiu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que posso fazer me ajudem por favor, estou fazendo um curso online de Python mas n posso praticar sem resolver esse problema

Comment: Acredito que isto possa ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-opening-microsoft-office-file

Comment: ele diz para reinstalar mas como eu já disse tentei reinstalar 3 vezes o Python